# Jmeter execution via command line finishes but the control does not terminates

Tags: jmeter, report, execution

When I run jmeter script via cmd prompt(local machine) for lesser thread user(5) and less time(2minutes) the execution is completed and comes out of the cmd control and the html report is generated. But for higher users(100) and high time(30 minutes) the execution is completed and the control does come out of the cmd.  I need to press CTLR+C to break the execution and with this the html report is not generated. In both the case i have selected Loop Count as Infinite.

Adding details of machine:
Processor i7, 16GB RAM

I have searched for all possible solutions but still with no valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the test doesn't finish after 30 minutes there is a reason which prevents it from doing this.

The best way of determining the reason is [taking a Thread Dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and seeing what exactly the threads are doing.

Most probably when it comes to the higher load your system under test simply stops responding and by default JMeter will wait for the response forever. The workaround would be defining reasonable timeouts. For [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler the best place is using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults), the Timeouts settings live under "Advanced" tab

[image]

Also make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as it might be the case it's JMeter who "hangs". Take a look at jmeter.log for for any suspicious entries. If there are no meaningful lines which can provide the necessary information - [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to DEBUG level.

Comment: I tried everything but still the same issue.